# r - trouble while plotting multiple line char

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset

```
--------------------------
query   triplestore time
--------------------------
inf.q1  jena    1246
inf.q2  jena    5083
inf.q3  jena    5979
inf.q4  jena    6503
cat.q1  jena    187
cat.q2  jena    13
cat.q3  jena    689
cat.q4  jena    311
int.q1  jena    1110
int.q2  jena    1207
int.q3  jena    500
int.q4  jena    696
occ.q1  jena    1274
order.q1    jena    1508
order.q2    jena    1304
order.q3    jena    1207
sem.q1  jena    4416
sem.q2  jena    3157
```

And I want to plot for each `triplestore` a line bar with `query` in x-axis and `time` in y-axis.

here is my code

```
w <- read.csv(file="plot.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",")

p <- ggplot(query, data=w, facets = triplestore ~ ., geom_line(aes(y=time)))

print (p)
```

but I get the following error

```
Erreur dans inherits(mapping, "uneval") : objet 'requete' introuvable
```

Does someone can help ?

Comment: Didn't you confuse `ggplot` with `qplot`? `ggplot` does not have such syntax. Check these links for help: [one](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/qplot.html), [two](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/ggplot.html).

Comment: @tonytonov nope it's ok, however do you have a simple way to do it ?

Comment: How about `ggplot(w, aes(seq_along(query), time)) + 
  geom_line() + facet_wrap(~triplestore) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=w$query) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90))`

Comment: @janzegan not excatly because this look like splitting a big line into piece, and the inconvenient is that in each piece we con still see blanck spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused, but is this what you are looking for? (the jena2 is my addition the show that facetting works)

```
p <- ggplot(data=w, aes(x=query, y=time)) +
geom_line(aes(group=1)) +
facet_grid(triplestore ~ .)
```

print (p)

As tonytonov pointed out, the syntax for ggplot is different!
[image]

Comment: Great ! you have the point. Any idea on how to ajust the y-axis values in each plot around the maximum value ?

Comment: Yes, see here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299425/change-y-axis-limits-for-each-row-of-a-facet-plot-in-ggplot2)