# ggplot2::coord_cartesian on facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggproto

`coord_cartesian` doesn't allow one to set per-facet coordinates, and using other range-limiting tends to produce a straight-line on the specific extreme. Since we have widelay-varying y-ranges, we can't set the limits on all facets identically; limiting the data before plot is not as friendly with `geom_line`/`geom_path` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27319786/3358272), as it takes a lot more effort to interpolate data to get to the edge and then insert `NA`s in order to break up the line. (Ultimately, the *only* way to get the desired result is to do exactly this, which can be a bit onerous with other data.)

One workaround is suggested in https://gist.github.com/burchill/d780d3e8663ad15bcbda7869394a348a, where it starts with

```r
test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Nsubjects, y = Odds, color=EffectSize)) +
  facet_wrap(DataType ~ ExpType, labeller = label_both, scales="free") +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=Upper, ymin=Lower, fill=EffectSize, color=NULL), alpha=0.2)
```

[image: ggplot2 with one facet needing better limits]

and in previous versions of `ggplot2`, that gist defined `coord_panel_ranges` and was able to control coordinates per-facet. The two right facets should narrow down to a 1-6(ish) y-axis so that the exploding confidence interval goes off-screen and allows the facet to focus primarily on the "normal range" of data. (Note: the `test_data` and this vis is not mine, it's taken from the gist. While my needs are somewhat similar, I thought it better to stay within the confines of the gist's data and code.)

Unfortunately, this now fails for me with `ggplot2-3.3.0`. Initial errors related to the recent loss of `ggplot2::scale_range`, which I tried to mitigate with this adaptation of burchill's code (that uses other `ggplot2:::` internal functions):

```r
UniquePanelCoords <- ggplot2::ggproto(
  "UniquePanelCoords", ggplot2::CoordCartesian,
  
  num_of_panels = 1,
  panel_counter = 1,
  panel_ranges = NULL,
  
  setup_layout = function(self, layout, params) {
    self$num_of_panels <- length(unique(layout$PANEL))
    self$panel_counter <- 1
    layout
  },
  
  setup_panel_params =  function(self, scale_x, scale_y, params = list()) {
    if (!is.null(self$panel_ranges) & length(self$panel_ranges) != self$num_of_panels)
      stop("Number of panel ranges does not equal the number supplied")
    
    train_cartesian <- function(scale, limits, name, given_range = NULL) {
      if (is.null(given_range)) {
        expansion <- ggplot2:::default_expansion(scale, expand = self$expand)
        range <- ggplot2:::expand_limits_scale(scale, expansion,
                                               coord_limits = self$limits[[name]])
      } else {
        range <- given_range
      }
      
      out <- scale$break_info(range)
      out$arrange <- scale$axis_order()
      names(out) <- paste(name, names(out), sep = ".")
      out
    }
    
    cur_panel_ranges <- self$panel_ranges[[self$panel_counter]]
    if (self$panel_counter < self$num_of_panels)
      self$panel_counter <- self$panel_counter + 1
    else
      self$panel_counter <- 1
    
    c(train_cartesian(scale_x, self$limits$x, "x", cur_panel_ranges$x),
      train_cartesian(scale_y, self$limits$y, "y", cur_panel_ranges$y))
  }
)

coord_panel_ranges <- function(panel_ranges, expand = TRUE, default = FALSE, clip = "on") {
  ggplot2::ggproto(NULL, UniquePanelCoords, panel_ranges = panel_ranges, 
          expand = expand, default = default, clip = clip)
}
```

but this is still failing with

```r
test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Nsubjects, y = Odds, color=EffectSize)) +
  facet_wrap(DataType ~ ExpType, labeller = label_both, scales="free") +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=Upper, ymin=Lower, fill=EffectSize, color=NULL), alpha=0.2) +
  coord_panel_ranges(panel_ranges = list(
    list(x=c(8,64), y=c(1,4)), # Panel 1
    list(x=c(8,64), y=c(1,6)), # Panel 2
    list(NULL),                # Panel 3, an empty list falls back on the default values
    list(x=c(8,64), y=c(1,7))  # Panel 4
  ))
# Error in panel_params$x$break_positions_minor() : 
#   attempt to apply non-function
```

I'm not very familiar with extending `ggplot2`, and I suspect there is something I'm missing from the ggproto. Here's what the return value from the proto looks like:

```r
str(c(train_cartesian(scale_x, self$limits$x, "x", cur_panel_ranges$x),
      train_cartesian(scale_y, self$limits$y, "y", cur_panel_ranges$y)))
# List of 14
#  $ x.range       : num [1:2] 8 64
#  $ x.labels      : chr [1:3] "20" "40" "60"
#  $ x.major       : num [1:3] 0.214 0.571 0.929
#  $ x.minor       : num [1:6] 0.0357 0.2143 0.3929 0.5714 0.75 ...
#  $ x.major_source: num [1:3] 20 40 60
#  $ x.minor_source: num [1:6] 10 20 30 40 50 60
#  $ x.arrange     : chr [1:2] "secondary" "primary"
#  $ y.range       : num [1:2] 1 4
#  $ y.labels      : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
#  $ y.major       : num [1:4] 0 0.333 0.667 1
#  $ y.minor       : num [1:7] 0 0.167 0.333 0.5 0.667 ...
#  $ y.major_source: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
#  $ y.minor_source: num [1:7] 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4
#  $ y.arrange     : chr [1:2] "primary" "secondary"
```

Do I need to have an `x` element that's a list with at least a `break_positions_minor` function, or is there something else that needs to be inherited in order to ensure `panel_params$x$break_positions_minor` exists or a reasonable default is used?

---

Data:

```r
test_data <- structure(list(DataType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    ExpType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("X", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    EffectSize = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("15", "35"
    ), class = "factor"), Nsubjects = c(8, 16, 32, 64, 8, 16, 
    32, 64, 8, 16, 32, 64, 8, 16, 32, 64, 8, 16, 32, 64, 8, 16, 
    32, 64, 8, 16, 32, 64, 8, 16, 32, 64), Odds = c(1.06248116259846, 
    1.09482076720863, 1.23086993413208, 1.76749340505612, 1.06641831731573, 
    1.12616954196688, 1.48351814320987, 3.50755080416964, 1.11601399761081, 
    1.18352602009495, 1.45705466646283, 2.53384744810515, 1.13847061762186, 
    1.24983742407086, 1.97075900741022, 6.01497152563726, 1.02798821372378, 
    1.06297006279249, 1.19432835697453, 1.7320754674107, 1.02813271730924, 
    1.09355953747203, 1.44830680332583, 3.4732692664923, 1.06295915758305, 
    1.12008443626365, 1.3887632112682, 2.46321037334, 1.06722652223114, 
    1.1874936754725, 1.89870184372054, 5.943747409114), Upper = c(1.72895843644471, 
    2.09878774769559, 2.59771794965346, 5.08513435549015, 1.72999898901071, 
    1.8702196882561, 3.85385388850167, 5.92564404180303, 1.99113042576373, 
    2.61074135841984, 3.45852331828636, 4.83900142207583, 1.57897154221764, 
    1.8957409107653, 10, 75, 2.3763918424135, 2.50181951057562, 
    3.45037180395673, 3.99515276392065, 2.04584535265976, 2.39317394040066, 
    2.832526733659, 5.38414183471915, 1.40569501856836, 2.6778044191832, 
    2.98023068052396, 4.75934650422069, 1.54116883311054, 2.50647989271592, 
    3.48517589981551, 100), Lower = c(0.396003888752214, 0.0908537867216577, 
    -0.135978081389309, -1.55014754537791, 0.40283764562075, 
    0.382119395677663, -0.88681760208193, 1.08945756653624, 0.240897569457892, 
    -0.243689318229938, -0.544413985360706, 0.228693474134466, 
    0.69796969302609, 0.603933937376415, 0.183548809738402, 3.57236968943798, 
    -0.320415414965949, -0.375879384990643, -1.06171509000767, 
    -0.531001829099242, 0.010420081958713, -0.206054865456611, 
    0.0640868729926525, 1.56239669826544, 0.720223296597732, 
    -0.437635546655903, -0.202704257987574, 0.167074242459314, 
    0.593284211351745, -0.131492541770921, 0.312227787625573, 
    3.76692741957876)), .Names = c("DataType", "ExpType", "EffectSize", 
"Nsubjects", "Odds", "Upper", "Lower"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -32L))
```

Comment: And before opening this can of worms, I take it you have considered and rejected other options such as stitching panels together or rescaling data and spoofing the axis labels?

Comment: Also, the example at the top works out quite nicely with an added `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 6))`. Presumably the end result is being able to adjust this on a per-panel basis?

Comment: Yes, per-panel basis. The example code sets the panels to different y-limits; in of my other uses (outside of this), the difference in y-range is orders-of-magnitude, so there's no reasonable compromise. For your first question, I had considered (and dismissed) it in the past, partly because legacy code was started before `cowplot`/`patchwork` proficiency, partly because there are several other plot aesthetics where merging legends just seems to over-complicate what I thought would be innate to the otherwise easy-to-use faceting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I modified the function `train_cartesian` to match the output format of `view_scales_from_scale` (defined [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/coord-cartesian-.r)), which seems to work:

```
train_cartesian <- function(scale, limits, name, given_range = NULL) {
    if (is.null(given_range)) {
        expansion <- ggplot2:::default_expansion(scale, expand = self$expand)
        range <- ggplot2:::expand_limits_scale(scale, expansion,
                                               coord_limits = self$limits[[name]])
    } else {
        range <- given_range
    }
    
    out <- list(
        ggplot2:::view_scale_primary(scale, limits, range),
        sec = ggplot2:::view_scale_secondary(scale, limits, range),
        arrange = scale$axis_order(),
        range = range
    )
    names(out) <- c(name, paste0(name, ".", names(out)[-1]))
    out
}
```

```
p <- test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Nsubjects, y = Odds, color=EffectSize)) +
  facet_wrap(DataType ~ ExpType, labeller = label_both, scales="free") +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=Upper, ymin=Lower, fill=EffectSize, color=NULL), alpha=0.2)

p + 
  coord_panel_ranges(panel_ranges = list(
    list(x=c(8,64), y=c(1,4)), # Panel 1
    list(x=c(8,64), y=c(1,6)), # Panel 2
    list(NULL),                # Panel 3, an empty list falls back on the default values
    list(x=c(8,64), y=c(1,7))  # Panel 4
  ))
```

[image: result]

---

## Original answer

I've cheated my way out of a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417358/8449629) before.

```
# alternate version of plot with data truncated to desired range for each facet
p.alt <- p %+% {test_data %>%
    mutate(facet = as.integer(interaction(DataType, ExpType, lex.order = TRUE))) %>%
    left_join(data.frame(facet = 1:4,
                         ymin = c(1, 1, -Inf, 1),  # change values here to enforce
                         ymax = c(4, 6, Inf, 7)),  # different axis limits
              by = "facet") %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Odds, Upper, Lower), list(~ ifelse(. < ymin, ymin, .))) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Odds, Upper, Lower), list(~ ifelse(. > ymax, ymax, .))) }

# copy alternate version's panel parameters to original plot & plot the result
p1 <- ggplot_build(p)
p1.alt <- ggplot_build(p.alt)
p1$layout$panel_params <- p1.alt$layout$panel_params
p2 <- ggplot_gtable(p1)
grid::grid.draw(p2)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Z.Lin, thank you for your answer! I've added an answer with an extension that is completely enabled by you fixing that error.

Comment: I normally don't like being targeted to look at a question, but my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76097621/control-per-axis-ggplot2-clipping) is directly related to this but with a new twist. I would really appreciate it if you could share any insight. Thank you!

Comment: @r2evans I've taken a stab at it. Thanks for thinking of me; it's a fun question :D

Answer (score 7):

Many thanks go to Z.Lin for starting the fix to my question, and that answer certainly helped me get past the errors and learn a more appropriate way of working with `ggproto` objects.

This answer is posted as more of a flexible method of fixing the underlying problem of per-panel limits within a faceted plot. The major issue I had with my first batch of code was that it relies on the ordering of the facets, which in some of my other (private) use-cases is not always known (well, not *controlled*) a priori. Because of this, I wanted an unambiguous determination of per-panel limits.

I've changed the function name (and the args) to represent two points: (1) this appears to be mimic/replace `coord_cartesian`, and (2) I don't know that it will translate to other `coord_*` functions without adjustment. Comments/patches welcome at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/6057f7995c117bb787495dc14a228d5d).

Up front, a perfect duplication of Z.Lin's results can be had with:

```r
p <- test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Nsubjects, y = Odds, color=EffectSize)) +
  facet_wrap(DataType ~ ExpType, labeller = label_both, scales = "free") +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = Upper, ymin = Lower, fill = EffectSize, color = NULL), alpha = 0.2)

p + coord_cartesian_panels(
  panel_limits = tibble::tribble(
    ~DataType, ~ExpType, ~ymin, ~ymax
  , "A"      , "X"     ,     1,     4
  , "A"      , "Y"     ,     1,     6
  , "B"      , "Y"     ,     1,     7
  )
)
```

and gone is the ambiguity (that the original code introduced) of *which* panel is *which* argument in the list. Since it uses a `data.frame` to match (usually `merge`) with the `layout` of the plot, the order of rows does not matter.

Notes:

1. the `panel_limits` fields referenced are: `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, and `ymax`, on top of whichever faceting variables are desired;
2. an `NA` in a particular field (or a missing field) means to use the previously-defined limit;
3. when *all* faceting-variables match (between `panel_limits` and the layout defined by `facet_*`), the limits are set on individual panels; this one-to-one mapping is the going-in assumption about this function;
4. when *some* (but not all) variables match, the limits are set on a subset of panels (e.g., on one axis of the panels, depending on the faceting method);
5. when no variables match and `panel_limits` is a single row, then set the limits for all panels indiscriminately; and
6. faceting rows in `panel_limits` that match nothing in `layout` are silently ignored.

Errors:

- any faceting variables in `panel_limits` that do not exist in the layout (i.e., not specified within `facet_*`); or
- more than one row in `panel_limits` matches a particular panel.

As an extension, this also handles a subset of the faceting variables, so if we want to limit all facets by `ExpType` only, then

```r
# set the limits on panels based on one faceting variable only
p + coord_cartesian_panels(
  panel_limits = tibble::tribble(
    ~ExpType, ~ymin, ~ymax
  , "X"     ,    NA,     4
  , "Y"     ,     1,     5
  )
) + labs(title = "panel_limits, one variable")

# set the limits on all panels
p + coord_cartesian_panels(
  panel_limits = tibble::tribble(
    ~ymin, ~ymax
  , NA,     5
  )
) + labs(title = "panel_limits, no variables")
```

(The last example seems silly, but if the facets/plots are being built programmatically and it is not guaranteed a priori that there are individual facets, then this will result in a reasonable default behavior, assuming that everything is otherwise unambiguous.)

---

A further extension might allow for an `NA` in a facet variable to match all, such as

```r
# does not work
p + coord_cartesian_panels(
  panel_limits = tibble::tribble(
    ~DataType, ~ExpType, ~ymin, ~ymax
  , "A"      , NA      ,     1,     4
  , NA       , "Y"     ,     1,     6
  )
)
```

This would require that `merge` understand that `NA` means "all/any", not a literal `NA`. I'm not going to extend `merge` at the moment to handle that, so I'm not going to complicate this function to attempt to do that. If there is a reasonable `merge` replacement that does this kind of calculus, let me know :-)

### *Many Thanks* to ...

- [burchill](https://gist.github.com/burchill) for the original effort and [gist](https://gist.github.com/burchill/d780d3e8663ad15bcbda7869394a348a); and
- Z.Lin, for helping to bring the function up to `ggplot2-3.3.0`.

---

```r
UniquePanelCoords <- ggplot2::ggproto(
  "UniquePanelCoords", ggplot2::CoordCartesian,
  
  num_of_panels = 1,
  panel_counter = 1,
  layout = NULL,
  
  setup_layout = function(self, layout, params) {
    self$num_of_panels <- length(unique(layout$PANEL))
    self$panel_counter <- 1
    self$layout <- layout # store for later
    layout
  },
  
  setup_panel_params =  function(self, scale_x, scale_y, params = list()) {
    train_cartesian <- function(scale, limits, name, given_range = c(NA, NA)) {
      if (anyNA(given_range)) {
        expansion <- ggplot2:::default_expansion(scale, expand = self$expand)
        range <- ggplot2:::expand_limits_scale(scale, expansion, coord_limits = limits)
        isna <- is.na(given_range)
        given_range[isna] <- range[isna]
      }
      out <- list(
        ggplot2:::view_scale_primary(scale, limits, given_range),
        sec = ggplot2:::view_scale_secondary(scale, limits, given_range),
        arrange = scale$axis_order(),
        range = given_range
      )
      names(out) <- c(name, paste0(name, ".", names(out)[-1]))
      out
    }

    this_layout <- self$layout[ self$panel_counter,, drop = FALSE ]
    self$panel_counter <- 
      if (self$panel_counter < self$num_of_panels) {
        self$panel_counter + 1
      } else 1

    # determine merge column names by removing all "standard" names
    layout_names <- setdiff(names(this_layout),
                            c("PANEL", "ROW", "COL", "SCALE_X", "SCALE_Y"))
    limits_names <- setdiff(names(self$panel_limits),
                            c("xmin", "xmax", "ymin", "ymax"))

    limit_extras <- setdiff(limits_names, layout_names)
    if (length(limit_extras) > 0) {
      stop("facet names in 'panel_limits' not found in 'layout': ",
           paste(sQuote(limit_extras), collapse = ","))
    } else if (length(limits_names) == 0 && NROW(self$panel_limits) == 1) {
      # no panels in 'panel_limits'
      this_panel_limits <- cbind(this_layout, self$panel_limits)
    } else {
      this_panel_limits <- merge(this_layout, self$panel_limits, all.x = TRUE, by = limits_names)
    }

    if (isTRUE(NROW(this_panel_limits) > 1)) {
      stop("multiple matches for current panel in 'panel_limits'")
    }

    # add missing min/max columns, default to "no override" (NA)
    this_panel_limits[, setdiff(c("xmin", "xmax", "ymin", "ymax"),
                                names(this_panel_limits)) ] <- NA

    c(train_cartesian(scale_x, self$limits$x, "x",
                      unlist(this_panel_limits[, c("xmin", "xmax"), drop = TRUE])),
      train_cartesian(scale_y, self$limits$y, "y",
                      unlist(this_panel_limits[, c("ymin", "ymax"), drop = TRUE])))
  }
)

coord_cartesian_panels <- function(panel_limits, expand = TRUE, default = FALSE, clip = "on") {
  ggplot2::ggproto(NULL, UniquePanelCoords,
                   panel_limits = panel_limits,
                   expand = expand, default = default, clip = clip)
}
```

Comment: Great question, and a great answer. I'm going to keep this bookmarked. Thank you for instigating the thread.

Comment: This function should be added in the arguments of `facet_wrap()` ! Or did I miss some conflicts with others ggplot func' ? Anyway, thank you for the brilliant solution provided, one of the best solution I've read here !

Comment: @ClémentLVD it's been suggested before. Not too surprisingly (and I cannot disagree), the largest rationale against adding it is: *maintenance*. If the current maintainers don't think it's generic enough and easily maintained within their current methodology, then they don't want to add it to that package. Remember, once it's in there, everybody can ping Hadley & Company to maintain this function, even if they had nothing to do with drafting it. The easy response: *"that's what extension packages are for"*.

Answer (score 3):

At some point I had a similar problem to this. The result was a slightly more verbose but also more flexible option that can customize many aspects of position scales on a per-facet basis. Due to some technicality it uses the equivalent of `scales::oob_keep()` as oob arguments on the scales, thereby acting as if the coordinates determined the limits.

```
library(ggh4x)
library(tidyverse)

p <- test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Nsubjects, y = Odds, color=EffectSize)) +
  facet_wrap(DataType ~ ExpType, labeller = label_both, scales="free") +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=Upper, ymin=Lower, fill=EffectSize, color=NULL), alpha=0.2) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(8, 64)),
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(64, 8), trans = "reverse"),
      NULL,
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(8, 64), labels = scales::dollar_format())
    ),
    y = list(
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 4), guide = "none"),
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 6), breaks = 1:3),
      NULL,
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 7), position = "right")
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting approach, I see goodness in it. Does this deal well with paths going oob and then returning in-bounds? That is, is it clipping the boundaries?

Comment: One of the sacrifices that I made to get this to work is that the oob argument to scales doesn't work, and resorts to the scales::oob_keep() behaviour. That is, it keeps out of bounds values and let the grid system clip whatever is outside the panel.

Comment: Well that's good, in a sense, so that lines/paths/ribbons just continue off the page, so to speak. I've actually seen your package before (and since lost the link until now). One of the things I was uncertain of is dealing with the relative uncertainty of the order of list elements, therefore my attempt to make the limits frame-based and order-agnostic. The fact that your package appears stable in light of this is encouraging, though I admit I'm still a little hesitant ... most of my plots are built significantly programmatically. Having said that, I really like the `scales`-agnostic approach!

Comment: Yeah using this grammatically can only work as well as you can predict what data ends up in what panel a priori. The i^th x scale is applied to whatever part of the `layout$SCALE_X == i`, so this is mostly under control of the facet system but should work both with the grid and wrap variants.

Comment: Have you ever looked into using `case_when`-like methods to match things up? For instance, `facetted_pos_scales(y = list( list(DataType="A", ExpType=1) ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 4)), list(DataType="B", ExpType=2) ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) ) )`

Comment: (Granted, that looks horrible in a comment, but it expands out a little better. Heck, one could *literally* use `case_when( DataType == "A" & ExpType = 1 ~ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1,4)) + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(10,14)) )`.)

Comment: (I chose formulas because `data.frame` can't store the return value from `scale_y_continuous`, but it can be virtualized within a formula and evaluated later.)

Comment: Update two comments ago to read `... & ExpType == 1 ~ ...`

Comment: Yeah I think it is a good idea to provide an alternative means to specifying the scales based on something other than the order. I've made an issue [here](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x/issues/25) to remind future me to explore the options available. (as an aside, data.frames can store lists of scales in a column as a list of environments. The `data.frame()` constructor won't allow it, but you can assign it after construction.)

Comment: Hehe, I had tried `data.frame(...)` but not `\`$<-\``.