# Is there a way to add facet.grid-type strip labels to regular plots so that plots aggregated in grid.extra match?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, facet-grid, strip-tags

It's my understanding that one of the big drawbacks of facet_grid is that you cannot specify the axis limits of groups of panels. Thus, I created four graphs, I added the axis limits I wanted and manually added them together using grid.arrange in the gridExtra package. However, I'd like if these plots match with the other ones I've created using face_grid. I think the bar labels that are auto-generated in facet_grid are controlled in theme() under the strip. related functions but I have no idea how to go about "recreating" these strip labels for my individual plots. Anyone know?

Here's the graph I've created with grid.arrange()
[image]

And here's the graph I've created with facet.grid()

[image]

I'd like the gray shaded labels from facet.grid() in my grid.arrange() generated plot.

Thanks!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: With a little bit of work (largely supported by https://stackoverflow.com/q/63550588/3358272), you _can_ apply different axis limits to each facet/group of `facet_grid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a simple approach would be to facet each of your four subplots by adding `facet_grid`. Doing so will automatically add strip text boxes to each of the subplots. In my code below I make use of a custom function and set the specs of each `facet_grid` conditionally using an `if-else`.

Using some fake example data and making use of `patchwork` instead of `grid.arrange`:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  row = c("K", "r"),
  col = rep(c("Female", "Male"), each = 2),
  x = rep(1:2, each = 4),
  y = rep(1:2, each = 4)
)

# Split by facet row and col
df_split <- split(df, ~row + col)
# Order
df_split <- df_split[c("K.Female", "K.Male", "r.Female", "r.Male")]

plot_fun <- function(x, y) {
  facet_layer <- if (grepl("Female$", y) && !grepl("^r", y)) 
    facet_grid(.~col) 
  else if (grepl("Male$", y) && !grepl("^r", y)) 
    facet_grid(row~col)
  else if (grepl("Male$", y) && grepl("^r", y)) 
    facet_grid(row~.)
  
  ggplot(x, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_layer
}

library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

purrr::imap(df_split, plot_fun) %>% 
  wrap_plots()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as you asked for a manual addition of strips (and I looked for the same, not able to facet my data), following workaround: just add manually text with grouping/factor name above a white rectangle

```
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0.8, xmax = 3.5, ymin = 29, ymax = 33,
           color="black", fill = "white")+ 
  annotate(label = "something", x= 2.15, y=31, geom="text") +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 3.9, xmax = 6.5, ymin = 29, ymax = 33,
           color="black", fill = "white")+ 
  annotate(label = "something different", x= 5.25, y=31, geom="text")
```

You have to fiddle a little with the positioning. Whenever possible I go also with the automated faceting mentioned before.